Evaluate function at all local extrema
I have an expression P[3,x]:=-1+30x-346x^2+2032x^3-6740x^4+13097x^5-14748x^6+8902x^7-2228x^8+x^9 and I want to find the smallest absolute value of the extrema of P[3,x] for x in $[0,1]$.
So I start with rs:=Nroots[D[P[3,x],x]==0,x] which gives a list x == 0.110696 || x == 0.201952 || x == 0.306843 || x == 0.499563 || x == 0.692947 || x == 0.798497 || x == 0.889249 || x == 1976.94 of extremal points. Then I try Map[F[3,x],rs] but this does not work. First off because F[3,x] is an expression in x rather than an actual function, but also because rs is a list of expressions x == ?.??? rather than a list of values. I can't find anything on how to evaluate P[3,x] in all the values I got from NRoots. I also still need to get rid of the roots outside $[0,1]$ and get the largest absolute value, but the main issue I can't solve is the evaluation at the roots of the derivative.

Could use NSolveValues like so. `In[64]:=
pol[3, x_] := -1 + 30 x - 346 x^2 + 2032 x^3 - 6740 x^4 + 13097 x^5 -
14748 x^6 + 8902 x^7 - 2228 x^8 + x^9
rtsin01 =
Select[NSolveValues[D[pol[3, x], x] == 0, x], 0 <= # <= 1 &]
Map[pol[3, #] &, rtsin01]
Out[65]= {0.110696, 0.201952, 0.306843, 0.499563, 0.692947, 0.798497, 
0.889249}
Out[66]= {0.0176866, -0.0126092, 0.0053057, -0.0605477, 0.00609643, 
-0.012208, 0.0177597}`

modified (Thanks @Roman's hint)
Try NSolveinstead of NRoots:
sol=NSolve[{ D[P[3, x], x] == 0 , 0 <= x <= 1}, x] 
(*{{x -> 0.110696}, {x -> 0.201952}, {x -> 0.306843}, {x ->0.499563}, {x -> 0.692947}, {x -> 0.798497}, {x -> 0.889249}}*)

extrema = Map[{x, P[3, x]} /. # &, sol];
SortBy[extrema, Last][[1]]  (*smallest extrema*)
(* {0.499563, -0.0605477} *)

Hope it helps!
addendum
To get extrema with smallest abs-value try
MinimalBy[extrema, Abs[#[[2]]] &] (*{{0.306843, 0.0053057}}*)


There's another extremum at $x = 1976.94$.

@Roman QP asked for extrema in he range 0<x<1!

Oh yes sorry. But the answer should be $x=0.307$, no?

@Roman Ohh that's correct, I didn't read Abs in the question. Thanks I'll modifiy my answer.

Use Solve for exact solutions: (note the underscore _ in the definition of P)
P[3, x_] = -1 + 30 x - 346 x^2 + 2032 x^3 - 6740 x^4 + 13097 x^5 - 14748 x^6 + 8902 x^7 - 2228 x^8 + x^9;

sol = Solve[D[P[3, x], x] == 0, x]
(*    {{x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 1, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 2, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 3, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 4, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 5, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 6, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 7, 0]},
       {x -> Root[30 - 692 # + 6096 #^2 - 26960 #^3 + 65485 #^4 - 88488 #^5 + 62314 #^6 - 17824 #^7 + 9 #^8&, 8, 0]}}    *)

P[3, x] /. sol // RootReduce
(*    long root objects    *)

See here for how to work with Root objects. For example,
% // N
(*    {0.0176866, -0.0126092, 0.0053057, -0.0605477, 0.00609643, -0.012208, 0.0177597, -5.7527*10^28}    *)

The minimum absolute value is for the $x$-value
MinimalBy[sol, Abs[P[3, x] /. #] &]
(*    {{x -> 0.306843}}    *)

P[3, x] /. %
(*    {0.0053057}    *)


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

P[3, x] := -1 + 30 x - 346 x^2 + 2032 x^3 - 6740 x^4 + 13097 x^5 - 
  14748 x^6 + 8902 x^7 - 2228 x^8 + x^9

Using NRoots
rs = Select[{NRoots[D[P[3, x], x] == 0, x, PrecisionGoal -> 20] // ToRules}, 
  0 <= (x /. #) <= 1 &]

(* {{x -> 0.11069606633604850944}, {x -> 0.20195236118999316928}, {x -> 
   0.30684319274472026808}, {x -> 0.49956293734084939843}, {x -> 
   0.69294682067307961468}, {x -> 0.79849687769058852123}, {x -> 
   0.88924876136599637956}} *)

Checking,
D[P[3, x], x] /. rs

(* {0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-17, 0.*10^-17, 0.*10^-16, 0.*10^-15, 0.*10^-15, 0.*10^-15} *)

